# ASA allow DNS service inside to be accessed from outside

Tags: networking, firewall, cisco-asa

I have a shared networking environment for tenants on our building, the ASA sits between a small business internet modem and each tenant's network.

```
Gateway Modem          Cisco ASA             DNS Server
192.168.001.254 <--->  192.168.001.253
                       010.000.255.001 <---> 010.000.255.002
(Tenant's Networks)    010.000.XXX.XXX
```

All tenants can access the DNS server with no issues, and we plan to add a VPN appliance on the Gateway's network (192.168.1.252) and would like it to use the 10.0.255.2 DNS Server.
I'm using ASDM but for the life of me, I cannot get it to function such that the DNS server is reachable from the Gateway's network using the ASA's outside IP (.1.253).
When I use the public server wizard in ASDM it tells me I cannot use the ASA's outside IP. What am I doing wrong?
Our ASA is running 9.12.2

```
: Saved

: 
: Serial Number: [REDACTED]
: Hardware:   ASA5512, 4096 MB RAM, CPU Clarkdale 2800 MHz, 1 CPU (2 cores)
: Written by [REDACTED] at [REDACTED]
!
ASA Version 9.12(2)9 
!
hostname firewall
domain-name example.com
enable password [REDACTED] encrypted
passwd [REDACTED] encrypted
names
no mac-address auto

!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description Gateway Access
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 dhcp client route track 1
 ip address dhcp setroute 
 dhcprelay server 192.168.1.254
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description Inside Trunk Interface
 flowcontrol send on
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.1
 description Default Native VLAN1
 vlan 1
 nameif Default-VLAN
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.2
 description 9831 datacentre VLAN
 vlan 2
 nameif 9831-DC-VLAN
 security-level 10
 ip address 10.0.2.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.18
 description 9818 LAN Segment
 shutdown
 vlan 18
 nameif 9818-VLAN
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.18.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.31
 description 9831 LAN Segment
 vlan 31
 nameif 9831-VLAN
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.31.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.34
 description 9834 LAN Segment
 shutdown
 vlan 34
 nameif 9834-VLAN
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.34.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.35
 description 9835 LAN Segment
 vlan 35
 nameif 9835-VLAN
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.35.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.75
 description 9875 LAN Segment
 vlan 75
 nameif 9875-VLAN
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.75.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.100
 description VPN VLAN
 vlan 100
 nameif VPN-VLAN
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.100.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 description Pi-Hole Dedicated Interface
 nameif Pi-Hole_Dedicated
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.255.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
 description ASA Firewall-to-Firewall Comm Link
 nameif Failover-CommLink
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.255.255.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Management0/0
 management-only
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
banner exec Please be sure to save any changes with write.
banner login Connected to Cisco ASA - $(hostname)
banner motd This system is for PRIVATE use only. All unauthorized access attempts will be logged and reported.
banner motd If you do not have existing authorization to modify this device, exit now.
boot system disk0:/asa9-12-2-9-smp-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
clock timezone CST -6
clock summer-time CDT recurring
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 domain-name example.com
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object network A_
object network example.com
 fqdn v4 example.com
object network ISP_Gateway
 host 192.168.1.254
 description AT&T Gateway
object network Gateway-Network
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
object network PAT-VLAN31
 subnet 10.0.31.0 255.255.255.0
 description 9831 VLAN PAT Configuration
object network PAT-VLAN02
 subnet 10.0.2.0 255.255.255.0
 description DC01 VLAN PAT Configuration
object network PAT-VLAN34
 subnet 10.0.34.0 255.255.255.0
 description 9834  VLAN PAT Configuration
object network PAT-VLAN35
 subnet 10.0.35.0 255.255.255.0
 description 9835 VLAN PAT Configuration
object network Aluminium-Can
 host 10.0.2.100
 description Server-AluminumCan
object network PAT-VLAN18
 subnet 10.0.18.0 255.255.255.0
 description 9818 VLAN PAT Configuration
object network any-to-VLAN02
 subnet 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0
object network MGMT-PAT
 subnet 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
 description MGMT network PAT
object network DEFAULT-PAT
 subnet 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0
object network pve.example.com
 host 10.0.2.99
 description Proxmox Host (1)
object network PAT-VLAN75
 subnet 10.0.75.0 255.255.255.0
 description 9875 VLAN PAT Configuration
object network PAT-PiHole
 subnet 10.0.255.0 255.255.255.0
object network VLAN31toPi
 subnet 10.0.31.0 255.255.255.0
object network PiHole
 subnet 10.0.255.0 255.255.255.0
 description PiHole Outside Access PAT
object network ASA-Outside-IP
 host 192.168.1.253
 description IP Assigned with DHCP reservation by gateway.
object-group network Inside-Networks
 network-object 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.0.18.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.0.2.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.0.31.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.0.34.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.0.35.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.0.75.0 255.255.255.0
object-group service web
 service-object tcp-udp destination eq 443 
 service-object tcp-udp destination eq www 
object-group service Minecraft_Server_Port tcp-udp
 port-object eq 65535
 port-object eq 65534
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object icmp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_2
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object icmp
access-list outside_access_in remark Allow all to DC
access-list outside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1 any 10.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_access_out extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_2 any any 
access-list inside_access_out extended permit ip any interface Pi-Hole_Dedicated 
access-list global_access extended permit ip any any 
access-list global_access extended permit ip object-group Inside-Networks object-group Inside-Networks 
access-list global_access extended permit ip object-group Inside-Networks any 
access-list Pi-Hole_Dedicated_access_out extended permit ip any any 
access-list Pi-Hole_Dedicated_access_in extended permit ip any any 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm notifications
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu Default-VLAN 1500
mtu 9831-DC-VLAN 1500
mtu 9818-VLAN 1500
mtu 9831-VLAN 1500
mtu 9834-VLAN 1500
mtu 9835-VLAN 1500
mtu 9875-VLAN 1500
mtu VPN-VLAN 1500
mtu Pi-Hole_Dedicated 1500
mtu Failover-CommLink 1500
no failover
no monitor-interface Default-VLAN
no monitor-interface 9831-DC-VLAN
no monitor-interface 9818-VLAN
no monitor-interface 9831-VLAN
no monitor-interface 9834-VLAN
no monitor-interface 9835-VLAN
no monitor-interface 9875-VLAN
no monitor-interface VPN-VLAN
no monitor-interface service-module 
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
icmp permit any outside
icmp permit any inside
icmp permit any Default-VLAN
icmp permit any 9831-DC-VLAN
asdm image disk0:/asdm-7122.bin
asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
arp rate-limit 8192
!
object network PAT-VLAN31
 nat (9831-VLAN,outside) dynamic interface
object network PAT-VLAN02
 nat (9831-DC-VLAN,outside) dynamic interface
object network PAT-VLAN34
 nat (9834-VLAN,outside) dynamic interface
object network PAT-VLAN35
 nat (9835-VLAN,outside) dynamic interface
object network PAT-VLAN18
 nat (9818-VLAN,outside) dynamic interface
object network MGMT-PAT
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network DEFAULT-PAT
 nat (Default-VLAN,outside) dynamic interface
object network PAT-VLAN75
 nat (9875-VLAN,outside) dynamic interface
object network PAT-PiHole
 nat (any,Pi-Hole_Dedicated) dynamic interface
object network PiHole
 nat (any,outside) dynamic interface
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
access-group inside_access_out out interface inside
access-group Pi-Hole_Dedicated_access_in in interface Pi-Hole_Dedicated
access-group Pi-Hole_Dedicated_access_out out interface Pi-Hole_Dedicated
access-group global_access global
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
timeout conn-holddown 0:00:15
timeout igp stale-route 0:01:10
no user-identity enable
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
no user-identity action mac-address-mismatch remove-user-ip
aaa authentication enable console LOCAL 
aaa authentication http console LOCAL 
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
aaa authentication login-history
http server enable
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 outside
http 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 inside
http 10.0.31.0 255.255.255.0 9831-VLAN
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
sla monitor 1
 type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 192.168.1.254 interface outside
sla monitor schedule 1 life forever start-time now
sla monitor 100
 type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 192.168.1.254 interface outside
 timeout 1000
 frequency 3
sla monitor schedule 100 life forever start-time now
sla monitor 111
 type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 8.8.8.8 interface outside
 timeout 1000
 frequency 30
sla monitor schedule 111 life forever start-time now
sla monitor 112
 type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 1.1.1.1 interface outside
 timeout 1000
 frequency 30
sla monitor schedule 112 life forever start-time now
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto ca trustpool policy
!
track 1 rtr 1 reachability
telnet timeout 5
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 10.0.31.0 255.255.255.0 9831-VLAN
ssh timeout 5
ssh version 2
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
dhcpd domain example.com
dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 10.0.0.10-10.0.0.250 inside
dhcpd auto_config outside interface inside
dhcpd enable inside
!
dhcpd address 10.0.1.10-10.0.1.250 Default-VLAN
dhcpd auto_config outside interface Default-VLAN
dhcpd enable Default-VLAN
!
dhcpd auto_config outside interface 9831-DC-VLAN
!
dhcpd address 10.0.18.10-10.0.18.250 9818-VLAN
dhcpd auto_config outside interface 9818-VLAN
dhcpd enable 9818-VLAN
!
dhcpd address 10.0.31.10-10.0.31.250 9831-VLAN
dhcpd dns 10.0.255.2 192.168.1.254 interface 9831-VLAN
dhcpd auto_config outside interface 9831-VLAN
dhcpd enable 9831-VLAN
!
dhcpd address 10.0.34.10-10.0.34.250 9834-VLAN
dhcpd dns 10.0.255.2 192.168.1.254 interface 9834-VLAN
dhcpd auto_config outside interface 9834-VLAN
dhcpd enable 9834-VLAN
!
dhcpd address 10.0.35.10-10.0.35.250 9835-VLAN
dhcpd dns 10.0.255.2 192.168.1.254 interface 9835-VLAN
dhcpd auto_config outside interface 9835-VLAN
dhcpd enable 9835-VLAN
!
dhcpd address 10.0.75.10-10.0.75.250 9875-VLAN
dhcpd dns 10.0.255.2 192.168.1.254 interface 9875-VLAN
dhcpd auto_config outside interface 9875-VLAN
dhcpd enable 9875-VLAN
!
dhcpd address 10.0.255.10-10.0.255.250 Pi-Hole_Dedicated
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics
threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept rate-interval 30 burst-rate 400 average-rate 200
ntp server 129.6.15.30 source outside
ntp server 129.6.15.29 source outside
ntp server 129.6.15.28 source outside
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
username [REDACTED] password [REDACTED] encrypted
!
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
  no tcp-inspection
policy-map global_policy
!
prompt hostname state context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
 profile CiscoTAC-1
  no active
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination address email callhome@cisco.com
  destination transport-method http
  subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
  subscribe-to-alert-group environment
  subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly 28
  subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly 28
  subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
hpm topN enable
!
rest-api image disk0:/asa-restapi-132200-lfbff-k8.spa
Cryptochecksum:0268c6b3eb40ef5acf968b8907aecb8d
: end
```

Comment: You need to crate a static NAT rule and an access rule for the DNS server.  Please edit your question to include the configuration file from the ASA.  You can use the `{ }` preformatted function.

Comment: The running-config calls the network housing the DNS server piHole since that was our old DNS, we've migrated to a real BIND instance since then but never re-named it.